# How to calculate prefix length for given IPv4 network mask?

Tags: c++, ipv4

I need to calculate the prefix length of a IPv4 network mask. My first naive approach is

```
int calculate_prefix_length (uint32_t address) {
  int set_bits;
    for (set_bits = 0; address; address >>= 1) {
      set_bits += address & 1;
    }
  return set_bits;
}
```

This is probably not very fast. is there a better solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer (first answer has O(1)-code)

Comment: (but use uint32_t, it´s written in the comments too)

Answer (score 2):

Netmak usually have 'n' number of '1's followed by 32-'n' zeros. so count the zeros first, subtract from 32 gives the number of '1's. Or you can count the number of '1's first if your network is class A. The following works faster for class 'C' networks

```
int calculate_prefix_length (uint32_t address) {
   int zero_bits;
   for (zero_bits = 0; (address & 1) == 0; address >>= 1, zero_bits++);
   return (32 - zero_bits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid branching by calculating count of bits set:

```cpp
    constexpr uint8_t numberOfSetBits(uint32_t i)
    {
        i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
        i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
        i = (i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
        return (i * 0x01010101) >> 24;
    }
```

See explanation and more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/4880243